# Display.show is not shopwing up sometimes post resuming backgrounding

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

This is part of my start() method

```
if(sm.user.getRole()==0){
            try {
                sm.progress();
                String str = WebServiceProxy.employerRequests(sm.driver.getDriverid());
                sm.dialog.dispose();
                //sm.closecurrentdialog();
                if(str!=null){
                    Result results = Result.fromContent(str, Result.XML);
                    sm.numberofexpiredemployerrequests=results.getAsInteger("/expireddriverrequests");
                    if(sm.numberofexpiredemployerrequests!=0)
                        Dialog.show("Expired Employer Requests", sm.numberofexpiredemployerrequests+" employer requests have expired", "OK", null);
                    sm.numberofemployerrequests=results.getSizeOfArray("/driverrequest");
                    if(sm.numberofemployerrequests!=0)
                        Dialog.show("Pending Employer Requests", "Employer(s) would like your response within 5 minutes", "OK", null);  
                    sm.openMainForm(sm.numberofemployerrequests, sm.numberofexpiredemployerrequests);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new DeliveryDriverException("Error on employerRequests (My Application)" );
            }

        }
        return;
```

After resuming backgrounding, Dialog(s) in the IFs is not showing up sometimes even though is has to. Anyways, when the dialog doesn't show up, if I tap the center of my cell screen, dialog shows up.

With the simulator, Dialog always shows up. This only happens with my android phone.

Answer (score 0):

We suggest recreating the `Dialog` and not reusing dialog instances.

Android is a bit problematic in terms of lifecycle handling, we actually have an improvement for this coming up in our build servers.

Comment: Where can I check upcoming codenameone builds (dates) to see if Dialog issue gets resolve? Otherwise to change my code to recreate Dialogs.

Comment: The build servers were already updated by now. So if there is still an issue then its something else.